# Substitution-based Operational Semantics of algebraic datatypes

Tags: functional-programming, semantics, operational-semantics

Assume, I want to define the operational semantics for some subset of ML.

```
e ::= \\x. e | e e | c | match e with p+ | A e*
v ::= ... | \\x. e | ... | A v*
p ::= A p* -> e | x
```

Where *e* is the expression language, *v* are the values or normal forms, *p* are the patterns and *A* are the constructors for my algebraic datatypes.

Also assume I want to define the semantics based on substitution, not on environments. Finally, the language should be typable, e.g. every constructor will only be allowed to be applied to the same number of arguments.

So I assume, I have to introduce a "construct" operation and a "data declaration" and then substitute every constructor with an appropriate datatype declaration. But how does one define this "construct" operation? And how does the data declaration look like in an untyped calculus?

Comment: You would need to say what your "construct" operation does. What does it construct?

Comment: The "construct" operation should create the value of one algebraic data type. The simplest way would obviously be to combine the constructor (or tag) A with the values that were passed to the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. Do you want to add a semantics for datatype definitions (e.g. `datatype t = A | B; \x. match x with A -> B | B -> A` should reduce to `(\x. match x with A -> B | B -> A)[some substitution]`)?

Comment: That would be the first step. The substitution would look like [A := ..., B := ...] and the part in the ellipsis is what I currently don't know how to define.

Comment: Just to clear my mind: what is the difference between a substitution and an environment ? ... since you want to replace one by the other.

Comment: Environments would allow to store the fact that A (in the example in the comment above) has no arguments. Then, when I either encounter a pattern containing A or a construction site, I can look that fact up. However, I want to translate a language to another (typesafe, sound) language which is defined in a small-step style with substitution and prove this translation correct. Hence, I want to stay as close as possible to that style.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my answer: ADTs can be represented by a combination of sum-types and tuples [enter link description here](http://books.google.de/books?id=ti6zoAC9Ph8C&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=sum%20type%20inject%20left%20right&source=bl&ots=EBFguCoXXG&sig=5-Eep5FmYPUwFsxsYAj35pJ2wZc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OwB5VI7gDYT4ywOezIKYDA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=sum%20type%20inject%20left%20right&f=false). In that representation, every construction takes exactly one argument (possibly the unit value).

Two special tagging forms, inl and inr for "inject left" and "inject right" are introduced. These forms allow the encoding of arbitrary tags. So every constructor is a one-argument function that applies the corresponding tag.

Hence, any data structure definition is operationally defined by the constructing operations:

```
data A | B | C  

=>

let A = \\x. inl x in
let B = \\x. inr (inl x) in
let C = \\x. inr (inr x) in
```

The corresponding pattern can be substituted similarly.